# Where is the location for putting SQLite db file in JAVA project?

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I am using eclipse for JAVA development in Windows 7 and I put my project in D:\workspace.

The following code is trying to connect to a SQLite database, While the jdbc address is `jdbc:sqlite:sample.db`, where is the location that JAVA is looking for sample.db ?

```
public class Sample{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException{

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

    Connection connection = null;
    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:sample.db");
        System.out.println("I got connection.");
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I have see there is example for using absolute paths, But I'd like to know where to put the DB file while I use Relative path.

Also, Does the file location be difference if I put the Class in some package ?

Answer (score 2):

By default the db file will be created in root of project directory.

Other path formats you can use along with sql lite are:

```
jdbc:sqlite://dirA/dirB/dbfile
jdbc:sqlite:/DRIVE:/dirA/dirB/dbfile
jdbc:sqlite:///COMPUTERNAME/shareA/dirB/dbfile
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite supports *on-memory database management*, which *does not create* any database files. To use a memory database in your Java code, get the database connection as follows:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::memory:");
```

If you want physical SQLite database you need to create SQLite database using [SQLite manager](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) or [Mozilla](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) or chrome add-on plugin.And give path like that

**Windows**

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/work/mydatabase.db");
```

**Linux, Mac OS X**

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:/home/leo/work/mydatabase.db");
```